# Deploy a test site azure devops pipeline (LAMP)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I've been looking at getting the pipeline build for automation E2E Acceptance testing going.

I've been able to get the pipeline running on an agent, now the default path that the code is checked out to is

```
/home/myusername/myagent/_work/1/s
```

which is `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`, and cannot be changed to custom path like `/var/www/html/` and accepts only relative path as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/checkout-path.md).

If I try to point the apache webroot to the above dir, I get the forbidden error. I tried

- running apache as the directory owner as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/164787/372069)
- giving full `777` permission to the directory

Now, how do I get apache to interact with those files or checkout the files inside the apache webroot `/var/www/html`in the first place so no additional work is required?

OS: Ubuntu 18

Comment: You should be deploying your application somewhere, *then* running tests against it. The agents are not designed for running applications. In any case, load testing should be taking place against a production-like environment, otherwise the results of the load test are completely meaningless.

Comment: I don't intend to load test in this setup. This is for test automation.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I misread -- "load a test" vs "load test". What I said still applies, though: The agents are not intended to be hosting environments.